# Magic The Gathering Card Draw Probability Function In C

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a function that will ask you your deck size, the amount of copies of a particular card you have in that deck, your initial hand size, the amount of cards you mulligan (we are setting the mulliganed cards aside drawing, and then shuffling the mulliganed cards back in), and on what turn you want to draw that card.

Essentially I am multiplying all the probabilities of NOT drawing the card together (and then doing 1 minus that probability) to give me the probability of drawing a particular card BY a particular turn. So far my function looks like this:

```
void card_probability() {

    int total;
    int numCopies;
    int n;
    int m;
    int turn;
    double initial_draw_prob;
    double mulligan_prob;
    double draw_prob;
    double neg_probability;
    double probability;

    printf("Enter how many total cards there are in the deck: ");
    scanf("%d", &total);

    printf("Enter how many copies of the card that you are looking for are 
    in the deck: ");
    scanf("%d", &numCopies);

    printf("Enter your initial hand size: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter how many cards you are mulliganing: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("Enter what turn you want to draw the card by: ");
    scanf("%d", &turn);

    initial_draw_prob = ((total - numCopies) / total);

    //for loop{}

    mulligan_prob = ((total - numCopies - n) / (total - n));

    //for loop{}

    draw_prob = ((total - numCopies - n - m) / (total - n - m));

    //for loop{}

    neg_probability = initial_draw_prob * mulligan_prob * draw_prob;
    probability = 1 - neg_probability


    printf("The probability of drawing at least one of the cards by turn %d 
    given you mulliganed %d cards is %lf", turn, m, probability);

}

int main(){
card_probability();

return 0;
}
```

I'm having trouble setting up these for loops to work correctly. Essentially what happens is three different probability sections:

1.) Probability of NOT drawing the desired card in your first hand
(total - numCopies) / (total) is the probability of NOT drawing that card on the first draw. Then for example if you drew 7 total cards you would keep going and multiply the probabilities together until you got to the term (total - numCopies - 7) / (total - 7)

2.) Probability of NOT drawing the card after you mulliganed a specified amount.

3.) Probability of NOT drawing the card BY the specified turn.

Can anyone help me set up these for loops? I can't get the increments correct. I did the math on paper, and with a deck size of 10, 2 copies of the card I want, a hand size of 2, 1 mulligan, and chosen turn of 3 I get 16.66% percent chance of NOT drawing the card => roughly 83% of drawing the card by turn 3.

Comment: Why do you have the C language in your title but C++ in your tags?  Which are you using?  For example, if you are using C++ you should use `std::string` for text and `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Comment: I'm using C. I have edited the tags. Thank you for looking out!

Comment: Prefer to use `fscanf` rather than the [dangerous `scanf`](https://www.google.com/search?q=scanf+danger&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - Your advice is flawed.   `fscanf()` is no more or less safe than `scanf()`.    The things that make both dangerous are related to possible mismatches between format strings and subsequent arguments, or buffer overruns (reading a number of characters to a buffer of insufficient size) when reading strings.

Comment: Your paper calculations are [incorrect](https://pastebin.com/m827Dw6f).

Answer (score 0):

So, when you're looking at the loops, why not just decrement an extra value?

so

```
int current_total = total;
for( int i = 0; i < opening_hand_size; i++)
{
  prob = prob * (( current_total - num_copies) / current_total) ;
  current_total--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we need the formula for the odds that a card isn't in a hand of `n` cards.

```
P[Not found after n draws] 
= (deck_size - num_copies - 0) / (deck_size - 0)
* (deck_size - num_copies - 1) / (deck_size - 1)
...
* (deck_size - num_copies - (n-2)) / (deck_size - (n-2))
* (deck_size - num_copies - (n-1)) / (deck_size - (n-1))
```

In C, this can be implemented as follows:

```
unsigned deck_size  = ...;
unsigned num_copies = ...;
unsigned num_draws  = ...;
float p = 1;
while (num_draws--) {
   p *= (float)(deck_size - num_copies - num_draws) / (float)(deck_size - num_draws);
}
```

or

```
unsigned deck_size  = ...;
unsigned num_copies = ...;
unsigned num_draws  = ...;
float p = 1;
while (num_draws--) {
   p *= (float)(deck_size - num_copies) / (float)deck_size;
   --deck_size;
}
```

The rest can be built from that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float p_not_in(int deck_size, int num_draws, int num_copies) {
   float p = 1;
   while (num_draws--) {
      p *= (float)(deck_size - num_copies) / (float)deck_size;
      --deck_size;
   }

   return p;
}

int main() {
   unsigned deck_size          = ...;
   unsigned max_mulligans      = ...;
   unsigned draw_on_first_turn = ...;  // boolean
   unsigned max_turns          = ...;
   unsigned num_copies         = ...;

   float p = 1;

   unsigned starting_hand_size = 7;
   unsigned mulligans_taken = 0;
   while (1) {
      p *= p_not_in(deck_size, starting_hand_size, num_copies);
      deck_size -= starting_hand_size;
      printf("Chance found after %u mulligans: %.0f%%\n", mulligans_taken, (1-p)*100);
      if (mulligans_taken == max_mulligans)
         break;

      deck_size += starting_hand_size;
      --starting_hand_size;
      ++mulligans_taken;
   }

   for (unsigned turn_num = 1; turn_num <= max_turns; ++turn_num) {
      if (turn_num > 1 || draw_on_first_turn) {
         p *= (float)(deck_size - num_copies) / (float)deck_size;
         --deck_size;
      }

      printf("Chance found no later than turn %u: %.0f%%\n", turn_num, (1-p)*100);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
unsigned deck_size          = 60;
unsigned max_mulligans      = 2;
unsigned draw_on_first_turn = 1;  // boolean
unsigned max_turns          = 3;
unsigned num_copies         = 4;
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o prob prob.c && prob
Chance found after 0 mulligans: 40%
Chance found after 1 mulligans: 61%
Chance found after 2 mulligans: 73%
Chance found no later than turn 1: 75%
Chance found no later than turn 2: 77%
Chance found no later than turn 3: 78%
```

Let's verify by obtaining the result experimentally:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( shuffle );

{
   my $num_trials = 10_000;
   my ($deck_size, $max_mulligans, $draw_on_first_turn, $max_turns, $num_copies) = @ARGV;

   my @counts;
   TRIAL:
   for (1..$num_trials) {
      my $i = 0;
      my @deck = shuffle(
         ( 0 ) x ( $deck_size - $num_copies ),
         ( 1 ) x $num_copies,
      );

      my $starting_hand_size = 7;
      my $mulligans_taken = 0;
      while (1) {
         my @hand = splice(@deck, 0, $starting_hand_size);
         next TRIAL if grep { $_ } @hand;

         ++$counts[$i++];
         last if $mulligans_taken == $max_mulligans;

         @deck = shuffle(@deck, @hand);
         --$starting_hand_size;
         ++$mulligans_taken;
      }

      for my $turn_num (1..$max_turns) {
         next TRIAL if ($turn_num > 1 || $draw_on_first_turn) && shift(@deck);
         ++$counts[$i++];
      }
   }

   printf("%.0f%%\n", (1 - $_/$num_trials)*100) for @counts;
}
```

Output:

```
$ verify 60 2 1 3 4
40%
61%
73%
75%
77%
78%
```

Spot on!